# How to add a resource based policy to a Lambda function created using AWS SAM via AWS CDK?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-sam

I am using CDK to create AWS SAM functions using the following code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from aws_cdk import core

from aws_cdk.aws_sam import CfnFunction
from aws_cdk.aws_iam import PolicyStatement, ServicePrincipal, PolicyDocument, Policy

import random

principal = ServicePrincipal("arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/rolename")

app = core.App()
stack = core.Stack(app, "cdk-test")

fn = CfnFunction(
    stack,
    id=f"CfnFn{str(random.randrange(1000, 1000000))}",
    **{
        "handler": "handler",
        "runtime": "python3.8",
        "memory_size": 256,
        "timeout": 10,
        "code_uri": "code_uri"
    }
)


app.synth()
```

I would like to invoke the Lambda function from another account, and would like to do this by attaching a [resource based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html).

This is easily achievable using `aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Function` itself by calling the [`add_permission`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/Function.html#aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Function.add_permission) method.

However, [`aws_cdk.aws_sam.CfnFunction`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_sam/CfnFunction.html) does not have an `add_permission` method. Is there an another way to achieve this using SAM (with CDK)? Or should I just leave SAM behind and switch to creating Lambda's directly.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done achieved with the help of [`AWS::Lambda::Permission`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html) using [`aws_cdk.aws_lambda.CfnPermission`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/CfnPermission.html).

```py
from aws_cdk import aws_lambda

aws_lambda.CfnPermission(
    scope,
    "CrossAccountInvocationPermission",
    action="lambda:InvokeFunction",
    function_name="FunctionName",
    principal="arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/rolename",
)
```